# How to add Dell Equillogic to Nagios

Tags: linux, plugins, nagios

Note: All firmware and models are compatible, that is why nothing is posted about it.

I've been working on this now for a few hours (reading manuals and such) so I'm not just coming here right out of the blue. I am working on a PRE-EXISTING Nagios server where there are several other existing plugins and checks running and working. Now I want to add another server there to check so I made the following modifications:

First and foremost, I added a file to /usr/local/nagios/libexec named: check_equallogic.sh. The permissions are 755, the same as all others. I have chowned to nagios:nagios and in the listing it shows the Owner as Nagios.

I then added a command to the commands.cfg file in \usr\local\nagios\etc\objects that shows the following:

```
# 'check_equallogic' command definition
define command{
    command_name check_equallogic
    command_line $USER1$/check_equallogic -H $HOSTADDRESS$ -C $ARG1$ -t $ARG2$ $ARG3$
}
```

Following this, I created a file named equallogic.cfg in the objects directory and it contains (more or less):

```
define host{
    use     linux-server        ; Inherit default values from a template
    host_name   172.16.50.11        ; The name we're giving to this device
    alias       EqualLogic      ; A longer name associated with the device
    address     172.16.50.11        ; IP address of the device
    contact_groups       admins
}
```

## Check Equallogic Information

```
define service{
    use                 generic-service
    host_name           172.16.50.11
    service_description         General Information
    check_command               check_equallogic!public!info
}
```

After ensuring that permissions are okay for all files, I restart the nagios service, no errors. When I go into the WebGUI, I get the following errors AFTER the check runs:

(Return code of 127 is out of bounds - plugin may be missing)

Extra, probably unrelated problem

Furthermore, when I log into the EquilLogic server, under Audit logs I get the following error:

```
Level: AUDIT
Time:  26/05/2014 3:59:13 PM
Member:  ps4100-1
Subsystem:  agent
Event ID:  22.7.1
SNMP packet validation failed, request received from 172.16.10.11
```

An snmpwalk receives a timeout, whereas others succeed. I will work on importing the MIBs tomorrow. The reason why I am mentioning it is because I want to make sure that it is only a MIB issue for the SNMP. If it is, then ignore this area.

I am entirely unsure of what to do here.

Comment: I think that ServerFault is more appropriate for this type of question.

Comment: Thank you very much rkon. I am not going to lie, I didn't know that existed. I posted it over there :).

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't look like a MiBs issue at all.

If snmpwalk fails, your device is not configured properly for snmp or the credentials in your possession are wrong.

Furthermore, on a general note, it is bad practice to create commands definitions for untested plugins. First you need to make sure that your plugin works from the command line, then you add it to Nagios' config.
Since I don't see this essential step in what you wrote, i will assume you didn't test the plugin.

If the plugin does not work and you need help with that please open a new question.